Dart convert List<Model> to another List<Another>
fixed : fixed the import path in the non DTO model, thank you everyone. oh my god the linter still navigate me to the file using CTRL + left click
hello good day everyone.
dart giving this strange error, i just converting my dto from API into my model.
var salesCategoriesDto =
        dataList.map((i) => SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto.fromJson(i)).toList();

var salesCategories = salesCategoriesDto
        .map((i) => SalesDailyCategory.fromDto(salesCategoryDto: i))
        .toList();

Error when passing iterated object

error trace message

the iterated item is giving error as if "cant pass or wrong type". am i missing something ?
SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto.dart
class SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto {
  String? lineGroup;
  int? daySales;
  int? monthSales;
  int? yearSales;
  int? totalSales;

  SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto._({
    required this.lineGroup,
    required this.daySales,
    required this.monthSales,
    required this.yearSales,
    required this.totalSales,
  });

  factory SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObject) {
    return SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto._(
      lineGroup: jsonObject["LineGroup"],
      daySales: jsonObject["DaySales"],
      monthSales: jsonObject["MonthSales"],
      yearSales: jsonObject["YearSales"],
      totalSales: jsonObject["TotalSales"],
    );
  }
}

SalesDailyCategory.dart
class SalesDailyCategory {
  String lineGroup;
  int daySales;
  int monthSales;
  int yearSales;
  int totalSales;

  SalesDailyCategory._({
    required this.lineGroup,
    required this.daySales,
    required this.monthSales,
    required this.yearSales,
    required this.totalSales,
  });

  factory SalesDailyCategory.fromDto(
          {required SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto salesCategoryDto}) =>
      SalesDailyCategory._(
        lineGroup: salesCategoryDto.lineGroup!,
        daySales: salesCategoryDto.daySales!,
        monthSales: salesCategoryDto.monthSales!,
        yearSales: salesCategoryDto.yearSales!,
        totalSales: salesCategoryDto.totalSales!,
      );
}

i am using dart 3.4.1
i tried not using private constructor the result is still same, also the linter know when using the dot on i its refering to SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto
error: The argument type 'SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto (where SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto is defined in D:\workcode\redacted\lib\features\sales\persentation\dtos\sales_daily_category_response_dto.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto (where SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto is defined in D:\workcode\redacted\lib\features\sales\persentation\dtos\sales_daily_Category_response_dto.dart)'.  (argument_type_not_assignable at [eth_sales_management_system] lib\features\sales\repositories\sales_daily_repository.dart:39)
folder structure

file in the folder


Is the error just "cant pass or wrong type"? Anything else?

@Nguyenfamily added picture of error trace message

You are having two SalesDailyCategoryResponseDto class in different files:
sales_daily_category_response_dto.dart

sales_daily_Category_response_dto.dart

Try remove duplicate code in those files

i already deleted the sales_daily_Category_response_dto.dart (the big C), i think its somehow cached. but still give me error.
EDIT : i fixed the import, thank you

Oh, maybe VSCode has that weird cache
